# Is there a linear regression based on the assumption of normal distribution and maximization of likelihood?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, linear-model

Usually linear regression is done by minimization of squared deviation:

$
E = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} [(c + k \cdot x_i) - y_i]^2
$

Where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the features and targets, respectively. While $c$ and $k$ are the model parameters that have to be found by the minimization of the above given measure (mean squared deviations).

For this problem we even have an exact analytic solution, so we do not even need to run a numeric optimization.

---

Now lets assume that the data came from a normal distribution in which mean and dispersion both linearly depend on the feature:

$
\mu (x) = c_{\mu} + k_{\mu} \cdot x
$

$
\sigma (x) = c_{\sigma} + k_{\sigma} \cdot x
$

In this case we can find parameters of the model by maximization of log likelihood:

$
L = \sum_{i = 1}^n \log \{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \cdot} |c_{\sigma} + k_{\sigma} \cdot x_i|} \exp [-\frac{1}{2} (\frac{c_{\mu} + k_{\mu} \cdot x_i - y_i}{|c_{\sigma} + k_{\sigma} \cdot x_i|})^2]\}
$

---

My question is whether the second approach is expected to give results different by those obtained with the first approach (I am interested only in $c_{\mu}$ and $k_{\mu}$).

I also wonder if there is an exact analytical solution for the second problem (likelihood maximization).

Comment: Your models are different. The first model tacitly assumes constant variance or equivalently SD. I've never seen the second model before. I would want to see a strong story of why it might make sense.

Comment: 1. Why do you state that the first model assume constant variance? I guess it does not make any assumptions about the distribution. It does not need any assumptions. 2. The second model is very simple we just assume that mean and STD of normal distribution linearly depend on the feature. Why it does not make any sense? Isn't even more realistic than assume constant variance?

Comment: Your first model is just the simplest standard regression model and discussed in every dedicated regression text. Alternative models are better phrased in terms of the variance, which can’t be negative. Your assumption allows the SD to go negative, which may not worry you for data you have in mind, but seems rather awkward to discuss to say the least. Variance proportional to mean is one of various alternatives.

Comment: @NickCox I see your point. I guess that the fat that SD can become negative can make analytical derivations not elegant. I do not mind to replace the model by assuming that variance linearly depend on the feature. I just want to have a simple deviation from the assumption of constant (features independent) variance.

Comment: The simplest interesting variation on constant variance in my view is variance proportional to mean. See hundreds of threads here on Poisson regression, quasi-Poisson, and (even more generally) generalized linear models (NB not general linear models).

Comment: It is possible to model the variance, but I think this is usually done by assuming $\sigma_i = \text{exp}(X_i \beta)$ rather than a linear function of $X$. This ensures the variance is positive. [Yiu & Su (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/asy015) use this parameterization in section 4.2.

Comment: Generalized linear models can deal with expressions where the deviation is a function of the mean $\sigma(x) = f(\mu(x))$ but in those cases there is not parameter fitting involved except for a constant factor (which doesn't need to be fit). See also [quasi likelihood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-likelihood)